# SQL to answer how many people of varying seniority you can hire under a budget

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with ID, seniority level, and salary (Postgres)

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  id int,
  seniority_level varchar(255),
  salary int
 );
```

The goal is to hire as many senior people under a budget of 40,000 and with the remaining money hire as many junior people. I have the logic to do this successfully but not in the proper format or handling certain conditions.

```
with total_cost AS
(
  SELECT 
    id,
    seniority_level,
    salary,
    SUM(salary) over (partition by seniority_level order by id ASC) as cost
  FROM people
),
senior_can_hire AS
(
  SELECT 
    id,
    seniority_level,
    salary
  FROM total_cost 
  WHERE seniority_level = 'senior' 
  AND cost <=40000
),
junior_can_hire AS
(
  SELECT 
    id, 
    seniority_level,
    salary
  FROM total_cost
  WHERE seniority_level = 'junior'
  AND cost <= 40000 - (SELECT SUM(salary) FROM senior_can_hire)
)
SELECT 
  seniority_level,
  COUNT(id) AS NUM_HIRES
FROM senior_can_hire
GROUP BY seniority_level
UNION
SELECT 
  seniority_level,
  COUNT(id) AS NUM_HIRES
FROM junior_can_hire
GROUP BY seniority_level
```

The idea is to display 1 row as a result with 2 columns containing the number of seniors you can hire and the number of juniors you can hire.

CASE 1:

```
INSERT INTO people values(20, 'junior', 10000);
INSERT INTO people values(30, 'senior', 15000);
INSERT INTO people values(40, 'senior', 30000);
```

My results are two columns, two rows: seniority_level and num_hires and a row for senior, row for junior each containing 1 in num_hires.

The desired results is 1 row, two columns: senior_hires, junior_hires and each value containing 1.

CASE 2:

```
 INSERT INTO people values(20, 'senior', 10000);
 INSERT INTO people values(30, 'senior', 15000);
 INSERT INTO people values(40, 'senior', 30000);
```

My results only give me 1 row saying you can hire 2 seniors. Desired results is 1 row saying you can hire 2 seniors but also indicating 0 for juniors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the following (after your existing CTEs):

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT count(*) FROM senior_can_hire) senior,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM junior_can_hire) junior
```

You can see it [working in a Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/uy9ExoeE).

However, I do think your first CTE should also likely be changed from

```
SUM(salary) over (partition by seniority_level order by id ASC) as cost
```

to

```
SUM(salary) over (partition by seniority_level order by salary ASC) as cost
```

It is equivalent in both of your examples, however unless you know for sure that `id` is always in the same order as `salary`, `salary` seems safer. You need to order that window function by `salary` to ensure you are maximizing the numbers of people who can be hired.

Here's an [additional Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TAsj8ZsZ) using the new example data (from the comments) where no senior staff can be hired. It uses `COALESCE` to treat `null` as 0.

Comment: Thank you! Had a major brain block on this. And yes good point I did that initially and was instructed to order by ID instead as the order of ID's ascending is in line with salary's ascending as well, very strange but whatever

Comment: Actually, the last scenario does not work with this, I think I need to revisit my CTE logic. The scenario is only Juniors

 INSERT INTO people values(20, 'junior', 10000);
 INSERT INTO people values(30, 'junior', 15000);
 INSERT INTO people values(40, 'junior', 30000);

I had to edit this CTE: 

junior_can_hire AS
(
  SELECT 
    id, 
    seniority_level,
    salary
  FROM total_cost
  WHERE seniority_level = 'junior'
  AND cost <= 40000 - (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(salary),0) FROM senior_can_hire)

Comment: To handle `null` senior salary, your junior CTE condition could be changed to `AND cost <= 40000 - COALESCE((SELECT SUM(salary) FROM senior_can_hire), 0)`

Comment: Any difference from wrapping the entire sub-select in COALESCE() rather than just wrapping the SUM(salary) which I did?

Comment: No, I don't think there's any technical difference here. My method was just what felt more natural to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
WITH senior_list AS (
SELECT count(*) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS count_senior
     , sum(salary) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum_senior
  FROM people
 WHERE seniority_level = 'senior'
), junior_list AS (
SELECT count(*) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS count_junior
     , sum(salary) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum_junior
  FROM people
 WHERE seniority_level = 'junior'
)
SELECT COALESCE(max(count_senior), 0) AS senior_hires
     , COALESCE(max(count_junior), 0) AS junior_hires
  FROM senior_list AS sl
  LEFT JOIN junior_list AS jl
    ON sum_junior <= 40000 - sum_senior
 WHERE sum_senior <= 40000
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8NOv69ST)